# Python. NLP. Preprocessing text

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, nlp, nltk

I've got a question with preprocessing my text corpus.
I want to delete all non-alphanumeric symbols from text. 
I have some approaches, but they don't exactly solve problem.

E.x. I've got a sentence:

```
A B C D ,5 .. AAA55AAA aaa.bbb.ccc
```

As a result I want to get:

```
'A' 'B' 'C' 'D' 'AAA' 'AAA' 'aaa' 'bbb' 'ccc'
```

I've tried NLTK:

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
tokens = word_tokenize(my_sentence)
```

but it has method **isalpha()**:

```
words = [word for word in tokens if word.isalpha()]
```

As a result it will be:

```
'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'
```

So it doesn't solve my problem. It deletes all words that contains non-alpha characters

And another:

```
import string
table = str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)
sripped = [w.translate(table) for w in tokens]
```

but it deletes only punctuation (and all word):

```
'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', '5', '', 'AAA55AAA'
```

Is there any solution using NLTK or smth. else? Or only way to solve problem - using regex for each word? (really do not want to do this because regex works for a long time especially on huge file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you use a [regex](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html)?

```
import re
rx = re.compile(r'[^a-zA-Z]')

res = rx.sub(" ", "AAA BB2BB")

print(res)  # >> AAA BB BB
```

> **What it does**: `[^a-zA-Z]` will match any non-alpha caracters and `sub()` will replace them by a space

Comment: Yes, I can. As I said " Or only way to solve problem - using regex for each word? (really do not want to do this because regex works for a long time especially on huge file)"

Comment: regex expressions really working for a long time, that's why I asked for any other solution with some NLP library

Comment: What if you do not use regex on each word but on the whole text?

Comment: I think you misunderstand my answer: you can replace the string I used ("AAA BB2BB") by a 200MB string if you want or more, it won't be slower than any python tokenizer; no need to process this string one word after another

Comment: Maybe you are right! Just another question - how can I save register of words, if I use stemming? When i stemmed my words, they all become lower case, but I want to save register

Comment: I'm not sure to understand? But it seems to be a different question from your first one, you should post a new question you certainly would get better answer that the one I could give you here in the comments...